# How to ensure list of numbers in excel column continues from the last non zero number

Tags: excel, formula

Imagine 3 columns, Column A and Column B and Column C.
Column A is a date column.
Column C is lookup column that looks up a value from 1 - 100 from a different table based on the date.
Column B is continuation of values from 0 from the first date value and continues with the value until the value in column c changes.

How do you formulate column B so it automatically keeps the last non zero value until another value in column C appears?

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | 0 | 0 |
| 03/01/2021 | 0 | 0 |
| 04/01/2021 | 20 | 20 |
| 05/01/2021 | 20 | 0 |
| 06/01/2021 | 20 | 0 |
| 07/01/2021 | 50 | 50 |
| 08/01/2021 | 50 | 0 |
| 09/01/2021 | 50 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(C$1:C1<>0),C$1:C1),0)
```

Or;

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,C$1:C1<>0,C$1:C1,0,0,-1)
```

Or, if these values are always bigger then the last one:

```
=MAX(C$1:C1)
```

Comment: Thank you JVDV. The first suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a spill formula in Excel 365 too:

```
=LET(range,C1:C9,
seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),
XLOOKUP(seq,IF(range>0,seq),range,0,-1)
)
```

[image]